# Return all matching rows in Oracle based on a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

Imagine a table - called `resume` - in a database that contains documents, and each document contains many components. The rows in this table can be either the document itself (the metadata for the document), or the components of that document:

```
row_id  name        resume_id  last_upd
1       resume_1               2010-1-1
2       section_1   1          2008-12-1
3       section_2   1          2009-6-1
4       resume_2               2010-1-1
5       section_1   4          2014-12-30
```

In the above example, rows 1 and 4 are documents themselves with additional columns containing metadata, and rows 2, 3 and 5 are components of the documents, which can be mapped with `resume_id`.

What I'm trying to do is return the full document (the main entry and components) from this table if any one of those rows (main entry or components) was updated within one year. If any element of a document is edited, only that row has the `last_upd` column updated.

Here's the query I've built so far, but it's pretty slow and I'm trying to sort out how to make it faster:

```
SELECT meta_data.row_id as "resume_id", 
       meta_data.name as "resume_name",
       components.name as "component_name"
FROM 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT(updated_meta_data.row_id) 
   FROM resume updated_meta_data 
   LEFT JOIN resume updated_components ON updated_components.resume_id = updated_meta_data.row_id
   WHERE ((updated_components.last_upd > (SYSDATE - 365)) or (updated_meta_data.last_upd > (SYSDATE - 365)))
) updated_resumes
LEFT JOIN resume meta_data ON updated_resumes.row_id = meta_data.row_id
LEFT JOIN resume components ON components.resume_id = meta_data.row_id
```

I think my query works, but in case it doesn't or if it's unclear what I'm trying to do, my query should return:

```
resume_id  resume_name    component_name
4          resume_2       
4          resume_2       section_1
```

Comment: You may want to think about renaming your columns to indicate a parent-child relationship?  row_id can be confused with Oracle rowid.

Answer (score 1):

The following should return all "documents" that have been updated in the past year:

```
select coalesce(resume_id, row_id)
from resume
group by coalesce(resume_id, row_id)
having last_upd >= sysdate - 365;
```

To get the full list of components, you can use `join` or `in` or `exists`.  Then you can join in the rest of the information:

```
select rs.resume_id, r.name as resume_name, c.name as component_name
from (select coalesce(resume_id, row_id) as theid
      from resume
      where last_upd >= sysdate - 365
      group by coalesce(resume_id, row_id)
     ) rs left join
     resume r
     on rs.theid = r.id left join
     resume c
     on rs.theid = rs.resume_id;
```

Comment: I dont think the subquery you wrote works - I pasted it in, changed the variables to mine, and got the 'not a GROUP BY expression' error

Comment: @sepiroth . . . Oops, that `having` clause should have been a `where`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query, assuming resume_id is null when it is the main document record. Else, use CASE expression.

```
SELECT meta_data.row_id as "resume_id", 
       meta_data.name as "resume_name",
       components.name as "component_name"
FROM 
(
   SELECT DISTINCT coalesce(resume_id, row_id) row_id
   FROM  resume 
   WHERE last_upd > SYSDATE - 365
) updated_resumes
INNER JOIN resume meta_data ON updated_resumes.row_id = meta_data.row_id
LEFT JOIN resume components ON meta_data.row_id = components.resume_id
```

I'm not sure why you were using LEFT JOINs, adjust as needed.

Comment: I used left joins because resume metadata rows can exist even without component rows, and i want to make sure i grab those, too. thanks for the help here!